# Qt two or multiple same signals calling slot only once

Tags: qt, console, signals

I'm sending two (or more) same signals, which receives one slot, but it is only called once instead of two times.. What I'm doing wrong?

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "app.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    App app;

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&app, "run", Qt::QueuedConnection);

    return a.exec();
}
```

app.h:

```
#ifndef APP_H
#define APP_H

#include <QObject>
#include "tcpserver.h"
#include "tcpsocket.h"

class App : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit App(QObject *parent = 0);

    signals:

    public slots:
        void run()
        {
            qDebug() << "run()";
            server.server_start(1111);
            socket.connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 1111);
            socket.write("hello", 5);
            socket.write("olleh", 5); // should execute slot two times.
        }

    private:
        TcpServer server;
        TcpSocket socket;

};

#endif // APP_H
```

TcpSocket.h:

```
#ifndef TCPSOCKET_H
#define TCPSOCKET_H

#include <QTcpSocket>

class TcpSocket : public QTcpSocket
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit TcpSocket(QObject *parent = 0);

    signals:
        void dataReady(QByteArray data);

    public slots:
        void readyRead()
        {
            qDebug() << "Bytes available:" << this.bytesAvailable(); // called only once.
            data = this.readAll(); // just for testing.
            emit dataReady(data);  //
        }
        void disconnected();

    private:
        QByteArray data;

};

#endif // TCPSOCKET_H
```

as you can see, I'm doing two socket.write functions, which should be handled two readyRead slots, but it is called only once. I honestly don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Regards.

Comment: What does readAll returns? "helloolleh"?

Comment: It's not wise to define a slot in a derived class with the same name and signature of a signal in the parent class.

Comment: yes, it returns helloolleh. I tried with different name too, still same result.

Comment: `QTcpSockets` does not work with datagrams, it works with data streams. You should cut your pieces of data manually. For example you could send size of data before sending actual data. And handle it on receiving.

Comment: try a `qApp->processEvents()` between you two write() calls.

Comment: Amartel, I know that, but I just demonstrated simple signal/slot problem here.

@cloose strange, but using processEvents() function still got same problems.

Comment: I've also tried using Threads (create new QObject and QThread and move QObject to QThread way), but it still has same problem. I'm just trying to make signals and slots work properly when I'm using infinite loops.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are expecting that two calls to write() should cause two calls to readyRead() slot. Unless you have some code you are not showing that directly connects write() to readyRead(). As Amartel already said, TCP works with data streams, not with datagrams. From what you are saying, your program seems to work as expected (when you know how TCP works).

Comment: It's not about the TCP protocol, I'll explain problem further. The code located in run() function is executed BEFORE the event handler will handle events (QCoreApplication::processEvents()). When I write two writes, program handles event after these two calls instead of one by one. I just want to handle each signal call with same count of slots.

Comment: What signals are you talking about? I don't see any connects in your code. Are you connecting something to the readyRead() slot? Show more code.

Comment: I don't have more honestly. as documentation says, readyRead SLOT is emitted when data is available. When I use socket.write function, it sends first chunk, however instead of triggering slot, it sends another chunk and when execution goes out from the run scope, readyRead slot is called, however it thinks that data is sent only once, not twice.

Comment: Well, as we have already tried to say: TCP data streams do _not_ work like that. One write() does not cause one corresponding readyRead() signal. The reading socket does _not_ known how the data got written to the socket. The data might have been written using one write() call or multiple write() calls. The written data is not immediately available for reading as a same size chunk it was written. There are no message boundaries in the TCP data stream.

Comment: somehow, when I modified like this, it worked fine, but isn't there any other way without calling these functions again and again?

    socket->send("hello", 5);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    socket->send("olleh", 5);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();

Comment: Another idea might be calling `QTcpSocket::flush()` after each write.

Comment: flush() method doesn't worked, still same result.